# date input to date format in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, date

In my component , from date input, i have an input that i get in cyyddmm format.

i need the change the date format from cyymmdd to dd/mm/yyyy

```
 function convertDate(ddmmyyyyDate){
        dateParts = ddmmyyyyDate.match(/\d+/g)
        cyy = Number(dateParts.pop()) - 1900
        return cyy+dateParts[1]+dateParts[0]
    }
    convertDate('980424')
```

Already tried this code but no success to do this `980424 to 24/04/1998`.

How can i get in string date format?

Comment: the question is not clear. '980424' is not a ddmmyyyy format. It's YYMMDD format. What are you looking for?

Comment: i need the change the date format from cyymmdd to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: what is cyymmdd format? what's the c in here?

Comment: never mind... how can i change it from 980424 to 24/04/1998?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the moment library to format dates. Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sun-dli0d?file=/src/App.js